# Determining the angle x through the point of intersection between lines in any triangle

Tags: trigonometry

I'm trying to determine the angle x in the triangle shown below.

[image]

Given $\overline{DB}=\overline{DE}$

Given $\overline{AD}=\overline{DC}$

Given $\angle ADE=40^°$

Find $\angle DCB$

But I'm finding it difficult to create something objective and practical.

I did a random study of values, but it was unprofessional.

```
textA=Text[Style["A",Medium,Purple],{-2.15,-.05}];
textB=Text[Style["B",Medium,Purple],{0,1.05}];
textC=Text[Style["C",Medium,Purple],{2.15,-.05}];
textD=Text[Style["D",Medium,Purple],{0,-.05}];
textE=Text[Style["E",Medium,Purple],{-.8,.68}];
l1={Red,Dashed,Line[{{0,0},{0,1}}]};
l2={Black,Line[{{0,0},{-2.15,0}}]};
l3={Black,Line[{{0,0},{2.15,0}}]};
l4={Red,Dashed,GeometricTransformation[Line[{{0,0},{-1,0}}],RotationTransform[-40 Degree]]};
l5={Black,GeometricTransformation[Line[{{0,1},{-2.37,1}}],RotationTransform[25 Degree,{0,1}]]};
l6={Black,GeometricTransformation[Line[{{0,1},{-2.37,1}}],RotationTransform[155 Degree,{0,1}]]};
Graphics[{l1,l2,l3,l4,l5,l6,textA,textB,textC,textD,textE}]
```

Comment: $EDB=50°$, so $EBD=65°$ so $x=BAD=25°$.

Comment: Are you really asking about how to find $x$? As understood points out that is simple geometry -- no trig needed. Perhaps you are asking for a better way to draw the diagram?

Comment: I don't think it's given that $ADB = 90^{\circ}$ since $AB$ may not be equal to $BC$...